# Do you say 'during sleep' or 'during sleeping'?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

Are they both correct?
Is there a rule to clarify?

The phrase is 'it is a device you wear during sleep/during sleeping'

Comment: Can you give me an example of a sentence you'd use it in?

Comment: I would use 'while sleeping', not 'during sleeping'. But an example to show context is needed to decide which or both.

Comment: I would say "while sleeping" but "during sleep" (probably the former more often, but it depends on the context).

Comment: The phrase is 'it is a device you wear during sleep/during sleeping'

Answer (score 4):

The word 'during' is used before nouns (such as "sleep").

E.g. I like to eat during lunch.

The word 'while' should be used when referring to verbs (such as "sleeping") and often a subject is used in between them.

E.g. He was eating while I was sleeping.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion ;  ''During sleep ''is more natural.
It has a good sound.

Comment: Depends on context, as the other answer states, one would normally go with either `during sleep` or `while sleeping`